# Load page and input values

Tags: javascript, checkbox

Is it possible somehow to open url, without loading it. Let me explain, I'm creating check-box which will let to create new log and automtically input values. I know how to take boxes and input value into them using javascript. But i don't know how to open that page without loading it on screen OR write that url that javascript would type values into that page.

Comment: Try to provide a [MVCE](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve) when asking for help. It helps to make clear what your problem is and shows what you already tried...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The concept you should read up on is AJAX. It sounds like it would fit your needs: post our data to a script, let the script do it's job, and work with the answer (or completely ignore the answer)

Since it seems that you are a beginner, maybe you might want to take a look at the [jQuery Ajax documentation](http://api.jquery.com/jquery.ajax/).